# Laravel Mix webpack alias - PhpStorm

Tags: webpack, sass, phpstorm, alias

I have problem to setup PHPStorm correctly for Laravel Mix and webpack. I tried every solution I found on google but nothing helped...
Any suggestions? I'm trying to setup alias for CSS and alias for JS in webpack.config.js (located in root)

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {

    resolve: {
        alias: {
            '@': path.resolve(__dirname, 'resources/_admin/js'),
            '~': path.resolve(__dirname, 'resources/_admin/sass')
        }
    },
};
```

Then I have webpack.mix.js with code

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');
const config = require('./webpack.config');

mix.webpackConfig(config);

mix.js('resources/_admin/js/app.js', 'public/_admin/js')
    .sass('resources/_admin/sass/app.scss', 'public/_admin/css')
    .options({
        processCssUrls: false
    })
    .extract();

mix.copyDirectory('node_modules/material-design-icons/iconfont', 'public/_admin/fonts/material-icons');
```

JS alias works ok but SCSS import in Vue component is still underlined.
Webpack works fine I have problem just with PHPstorm. Autocomplete doesn't work and there are warnings.

I already put webpack.config.js into PHPstorm settings...

Any suggestions?

Comment: what do you sass imports look like? please attach screenshots

Comment: I figured it out... It looks like PHPstorm has problem with '~' alias. When I tries to use '~sass' everything works as expected

Comment: `~` has a special meaning for sass loader.. see https://github.com/webpack-contrib/sass-loader#resolving-import-at-rules